# when $\lim_{n\to\infty }\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis

When does $$\lim_{n\to\infty }\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k\ \ ?$$

**My first way :** Since $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k=(1+x)^n$$
the limit exist when $x\in ]-2,0]$ et it's limits is $0$ when $x\in ]-2,0[$ and $1$ if $x=0$.

**My second way :** Using D'Alembert, I have that $$\lim_{k\to \infty }\left|\frac{\binom{n}{k+1}}{\binom{n}{k}}\right|=\lim_{k\to\infty }\left|\frac{n-k}{k+1}\right|=1$$
and thus it converge if $|x|<1$. Therefore I find the convergence for $x\in ]-1,1[$ what contradict my first answer.

**What is the problem ?**

Comment: Using d'Alembert is invalud here, since terms in the series vary when $n$ changes.

Comment: your first approach is legitimate

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the series is defined as
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n}{a_k}.$$

Your example does not fit into the definition, because you would have

$$a_k = \binom{n}{k}x^k$$

and your $a_k$ would depend on $n$, but $n$ is different for different partial sums. So this is not description of infinite series and you cannot use D'Alembert ratio test. Your second approach is not valid.